# epslatex in gnuplot does not give right output

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I am using the following script to generate a simple eps image:

```
set terminal epslatex 8
set output 'sample1.tex'
set size 0.75,0.75
set xrange [-pi:pi]
set yrange [0:1.2]
set xlabel "$x$"
set ylabel "$y$"
plot sin(x)*sin(x) title "$\\sin^2(x)$"
```

However, when I run it in gnuplot

```
gnuplot> load "sample.gpi"
```

I got a blank image, just the grids without numbers are shown.
Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably viewing the `sample1-inc.eps` file. But you must compile the output LaTeX-file first. For this it is very convenient to use the `standalone` option and compile from within the script itself:

```
set terminal epslatex 8 standalone
set output 'sample1.tex'
set size 0.75,0.75
set xrange [-pi:pi]
set yrange [0:1.2]
set xlabel "$x$"
set ylabel "$y$"
plot sin(x)*sin(x) title "$\\sin^2(x)$"

set output # finish the current output file
system('latex sample1.tex && dvips sample1.dvi && ps2pdf sample1.ps')
```

Now you can `load 'sample1.gpi'` and view the complete output as `sample1.ps` or `sample1.pdf`. If you are on Windows you may need to compile with three separate `system` calls (just guessing):

```
system('latex sample1.tex')
system('dvips sample1.dvi')
system('ps2pdf sample1.ps')
```