# Gnuplot epslatex text missing

Tags: gnuplot, postscript

I need to put some things from LaTeX into my plots in `.eps` format. I'm trying to use `set terminal epslatex standalone`. But when I'm trying to plot something, there is no labels or titles at all in `.eps` file. Also, following lines appear in `.tex` file:

```
\GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Gnuplot Error: File `size10.clo' not found! Could not set font size%
   }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
   }{For using a font size a file `size<fontsize>.clo' has to exist.
        Falling back ^^Jto default fontsize 10pt.}%
```

I think the problem is that gnuplot can not find any size-file and draw any text.
I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and GnuPlot 5.0 patchlevel 3.May be, I missed some details, I'm not very skillful user.
Is there any way to fix this issue? Or may be there is another method to put LaTeX signs, like `\varkappa` or `\mathcal{}`, into `.ps` plots?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20347095/2604213

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm bad at searching.